# angularjs value need to pass in php variable

Tags: php, angularjs

can i do something like this in php
the **angular js** value will assign into php value, any tricks?

```
$phpVariable={{automation.start_flag}};
    //echo $phpVariable;
    <td> <?php echo  $phpVariable ?></td>
```

**want pass a angular js value to php variable**
can anyone help me to do it?

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$http({method: 'GET',url: '/someUrl'})
.success(function (response) {
   $scope.resp = response
}, function(response) {
   console.log(response)
});
```

HTML

```
<div>{{resp}}<div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Used ajax request:

```
$http({
        url: "YOUR_URL.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            data: variable
        }
    }).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

For backend you can get the variable:

```
<?php
$your_request = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
$your_variable = $your_request->data
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

AngularJS

```
angular.module('scopeExample', []).controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.username = '<?php echo $phpVariable; ?>'

  $scope.sayHello = function() {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + '<?php echo $phpVariable; ?>' + '!';
  };
}]);
```

HTML

```
<td> {{username}}</td>
<td ng-init="sayHello"> {{greeting}}</td>
```

Comment: basically i dont want php value to angularjs, i want angular js value to php variable